# Proving that a Turing machine is deterministic using instantaneous descriptions

Tags: logic, formal-languages, turing-machines

We define an instantaneous description of a Turing machine as a word $\alpha p \beta$, with $\alpha, \beta \in \Sigma^{*}$ and $q \in Q$, s.t. if

$$
d = \alpha_1 \ldots \alpha_n q \beta_1 \ldots \beta_n
$$

we read "the Turing machine is at state $q$, with $\alpha, \beta$ on the tape and its head over $\beta_1$". Thus, an instantenous description describes what is in the tape of the Turing machine, where the machine's head is, and what state the machine is in.

We say $d \vdash d'$ if and only if

- $d$ contains $q$ and $d'$ contains $q'$, each a state of $Q$;
- if the machine's description is $d$, then after $\delta(q)$ the machine's description is $d'$.

I'll provide an example to make sure this is clear:

> Let $\Sigma = \{ @, \#\}$. Assuming $\delta (p) = \{ (q,\#, K) \}$.
> \begin{align*}
>         &@ ~ \# ~ @ ~ p ~ @ ~ @ ~ @ ~ B ~ B ~ B \ldots \vdash  @ ~ \# ~@ ~ q ~ \# ~  @ ~
>         @~ B ~ B
>         ~ \ldots
> \end{align*}
> where $B$ is the blank symbol.

One very important point is that, for a given instantaneous description $\alpha q \beta$, $\vdash$ is not defined if $\delta(q) = \{(q', \sigma, L\}$ and $\alpha = \varepsilon$. Informally, the machine cannot move left if there is no symbol to the left of the current head's position.

I was asked to prove the following statement:

> Prove that $M$ is deterministic iff for each instantaneous description $d$ there is at most one instantaneous description $d'$ s.t. $d \vdash d'$.

This statement seems to be false! Consider the $(\Leftarrow)$ case; this is, assume that for each description $d = \alpha q \beta$ there is at most one $d'$ s.t. $d \vdash d'$. Consider the case where there is no $d'$ s.t. $d \vdash d'$. In the case where $\alpha = \varepsilon$ and

$$
\delta(q) = \{ (q', \sigma, L), (q'', \sigma', L) \}
$$

the machine is non-deterministic without violating the assumption. In other words, that $d \vdash d'$ for at most one $d'$ does not seem to imply that the machine is deterministic.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/165412/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4857563/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that rule, I apologize. Will delete my post in cs stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right. You can add arbitrary unreachable states to the description of a Turing machine without affecting whether or not it is deterministic. Also the notion of a reachable state is undecidable, so there can be no effective test for whether a Turing machine is deterministic. It is true that, if there at most one successor state for any instantaneous description, then the Turing machine is deterministic.

Comment: Good to have my intuition confirmed. Then the error is in the book I suppose.

Comment: Yes, the book is wrong. Probably just a typo: "iff" for "if".